# Why does the computation for MAML only improve by 33% when removing higher order gradients?

Tags: machine-learning, neural-networks, optimization

I was reading the paper [MAML](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1703.03400.pdf) and they say:

> which we found led to
>   roughly 33% speed-up in network computation.

Which I thought was surprising because from my knowledge (https://www.quora.com/What-is-the-runtime-to-compute-the-hessian-of-a-function) it usually takes at least $O(n^2)$ or even $O(n^3)$ to compute Hessians. If that is the case then was the speed up only 33%? I would have expected orders of magnitude perhaps...at least a number great than 1 say double...

Answer (score 1):

It's not necessary (nor is it feasible) to compute the hessian. However in MAML, only the *Hessian vector product* is necessary, since $\nabla f(x+d) \approx \nabla f(x) + H(x)d$.

It turns out that we can just compute this using $2\epsilon \cdot H(x)d \approx \nabla f(x+\epsilon d) - \nabla f(x-\epsilon d)$, which takes just 2 evaluations of the gradient.

Comment: why is it not feasible to compute the hessian? Also, why does MAML only need Hessian vector products?